# Xcode Local SVN

Tags: svn, xcode

As I get into more serious project development in Xcode I decided to setup a local SVN repo. It seemed surprisingly easy and now I'm checking in and out files within XCode.

Two quick questions.

After adding a few files and commit some other changes, a 'M' has appeared at the top level of the Xcode "Groups & Files" column. I assume 'M' stands for merge (as I've noticed it appears when I modify files) but why does it now appear next to the top level project icon with no changes and visible options?

Also newbie question but I checked a base version of my 7MB Xcode project and then copied it into a branch. Yet my SVN directory is still under 3MB. Is this just SVN goodness or am I missing something? Is it safe to assume that if I backup and save the SVN directory I have saved my world?

Answer (score 1):

'M' stands for 'Modified'. If the project file appears to be modified (but nothing underneath it), it may be that XCode is updating the project file to a newer format.

Comment: Ah interesting. Yeah that is the scenario. There is nothing else labelled 'M' below I even did an update of the entire project.

And now I just noticed that if I close Xcode and reopen the project. The 'M' is not visible. Interesting.

Comment: The project file is a wrapper containing many files, including your user file (which persists your window geometry, breakpoints, etc.)  If any repo file in the wrapper is modified, the whole project shows M.  So if you have committed your .pbxuser file to the repository, your project file will almost always show M, even though committing it will only change your user file.

Answer (score 0):

I found XCode's interaction with the SVN to be a little weak, so I now use [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/) to handle the SVN.

[Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and all that :)

**Note:** CW because this doesn't actually answer the question, but it was too long for a comment.